# How to make Sendmail add an evelope recipient(s) header to all inbound email messages?

Tags: sendmail, rules, smtp-headers

**Disclaimer:** I have read some of the questions and articles here and elsewhere which deal with Sendmail rewriting headers. I haven't found an answer to the question below because the other question mostly relate to *rewriting* headers (instead of adding them), and nearly all of them relate to *outbound* messages and the envelope *sender* (instead of the envelope recipient).

**Having said this:**

I am running a mail server, using Sendmail 8.14.4 under Debian jessie.

There are some email recipient addresses which are mapped to the same O/S user account. When the respective O/S user reads the messages, he can't determine to what email address the messages originally have been sent.

Therefore, I would like to have Sendmail add a custom header containing the envelope recipient(s) to all inbound email messages.

I think I could better explain my problem by example:

Suppose I have two email addresses, `offer1@example.com` and `offer2@example.com`. Both are mapped to the O/S user account `offers`. This works so far: The O/S user `offers`, when fetching his email, gets all messages sent to `offer1@example.com` and `offer2@example.com`.

The problem now is that he can't determine to which email address each message originally has been sent. That means: Although he is seeing all messages which have been sent to both email addresses, he can't tell if a certain message has been originally sent to `offer1@example.com` or to `offer2@example.com`.

Therefore, I would like to add a custom header to each inbound message, perhaps something like that: `X-Envelope-Recipient: <Original envelope recipient>`.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Once upon a time, I have written some simple custom rules for Sendmail. But nearly 15 years have passed since then, so I'd like to avoid that, and thus I hope that there is an easy solution or that somebody could point me in the right direction. To be honest, writing a milter to solve my problem currently seems easier to me than re-learning Sendmail's rule syntax ...

**EDIT 1**

As requested by @AnFi, here is the local mailer definition from sendmail.cf:

```
Mlocal,         P=/usr/lib/sm.bin/mail.local, F=lsDFMAw5:/|@qPSXnz9, S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromL, R=EnvToL/HdrToL,
                T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
                A=mail.local -l -h inbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is addresses by Sendmail.org FAQ 3.29

> 3.29 How can I add a header specifying the actual recipient when having multiple users in a virtual domain go to a single mailbox?

Short version:  Use virtusertable and `~offers/.procmailrc`

virtusertable:

```
offer1@example.com  offers+offer1
offer2@example.com  offers+offer2
```

`~offers/.procmailrc` should get "plus detail" in `$1`.
**OR**
You can use $h (set to +detail) in custom headers

**Warning**: you will get/process two copies of a message addressed to both `offer1@example.com` and `offer2@example.com`

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1, but: Actually, I have been searching for a solution which does not involve "external" tools. That is why I wrote that *Sendmail* should add the header. However, since I eventually have not been clear enough about that, I'll give the answer to you after waiting a few more days ...

Comment: 1) You can make sendmail.cf add custom header(s).  You can use `$h` (+detail in case of many local mailers) in such headers.  2) Post your local mailer definition from `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` [A few lines after `Mlocal`]

Comment: Thanks for bothering. Please see section EDIT 1 in my original question where I am showing the local mailer definition from `sendmail.cf`. I'll try to find out more about `mail.local` in the meantime. Are you suggesting using `.forward` files instead? The reason why I would like to have this done as deep in Sendmail as possible is that I would like to avoid playing around with files users have crafted, or to urge users to play around with them, i.e. I would like to avoid changing anything in users' home directories.

Comment: Could also post what is reported by `sendmail -bv offers+offer1` executed by root?  Local mailer definition does not pass `$h` (+detail) to local mailer program but sendmail.cf may set it anyway.

Comment: Thanks again - since the output is short, here we go: `offers+offer1... deliverable: mailer local, host offer1, user offers`.

Comment: So your sendmail,cf sets `$h` to +detail. [ `$h` keeps "next hop host" for typical mailer]

Comment: I am giving the answer to you because your solution would probably work. However, the method is very illogical (why do I have to use plussed addresses to achieve such a simple thing?) and worrying (why does this work at all given that `$h` usually contains the *host* part?). Additionally, I wanted a solution which would show me *all* RCPT-TO addresses in that header, not just the one(s) which map to the respective (O/S-level) user. Therefore, I now simply have written a milter which does exactly what I want, transparently for *all* users, without fiddling with any configuration files.

Comment: In fact, it already has been tested thoroughly the last two days. It works as expected. Understanding the `libmilter` API is not that hard, but I admit that I already have written my first milter some months ago, which made writing this one much easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest would be against the SMTP protocol: there's legitimate reasons for adding addresses to `RCPT TO` command despite they do not exist in the `To:` or `Cc:` headers, i.e. [RFC 5321 7.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-7.2) "Blind" Copies (emphasis is mine):

> Addresses that do not appear in the message header section may
> appear in the RCPT commands to an SMTP server for a number of
> reasons.  The two most common involve the use of a mailing address
> as a "list exploder" (a single address that resolves into multiple
> addresses) and the appearance of "blind copies".  Especially when
> more than one RCPT command is present, and in order to avoid
> defeating some of the purpose of these mechanisms, **SMTP clients and
> servers SHOULD NOT copy the full set of RCPT command arguments into
> the header section, either as part of trace header fields or as
> informational or private-extension header fields**.  Since this rule
> is often violated in practice, and cannot be enforced, sending SMTP
> systems that are aware of "bcc" use MAY find it helpful to send
> each blind copy as a separate message transaction containing only a
> single RCPT command.
>
> There is no inherent relationship between either "reverse" (from
> MAIL, SAML, etc., commands) or "forward" (RCPT) addresses in the SMTP
> transaction ("envelope") and the addresses in the header section.
> Receiving systems SHOULD NOT attempt to deduce such relationships and
> use them to alter the header section of the message for delivery.
> **The popular `Apparently-to` header field is a violation of this
> principle as well as a common source of unintended information
> disclosure and SHOULD NOT be used.**

The non-recommended `Apparently-to` header is controlled with option `NoRecipientAction=action`.

> Set the behaviour when there are no recipient headers (`To:`, `Cc:` or
> `Bcc:`) in the message to action:

> - `none` leaves the message unchanged,
> - `add-to` adds a `To:` header with the envelope recipients,
> - `add-apparently-to` adds an `Apparently-To:` header with the envelope
>   recipients,
> - `add-bcc` adds an empty `Bcc:` header, and
> - `add-to-undisclosed`
>   adds a header reading `'To: undisclosed-recipients:;'`.

Please note that normally the original recipient address is already in the `To:` or `Cc:` header. It should not be modified to the user account name `offers`, so it's either `offer1@example.com`, `offer2@example.com` or hidden. Rewriting headers has become even more dangerous as it might also broke DKIM signatures. The only reasonable use case is address rewriting for mail with a local origin (`user` to `user@example.com`).

---

Adding a list of all `RCPT TO` addresses would violate the protocol, but you actually simply need the **single original `RCPT TO` address** for the user the mail was delivered to. I don't know how to achieve this with Sendmail, but **Postfix** (with the default configuration) **adds an `X-Original-To:`** header containing exactly that, and additionally a `Delivered-To:` header containing the internal destination mailbox (`user@FQDN.example.com`).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! *...is already in the `To:` or `Cc:` header...* But this is exactly my problem: This is not the case. There is no `Cc:` header at all, and the `To:` header contains something like `verysillynonsensehere`. The senders of those messages often "fake" the `To:` header by intention. Exactly in such cases, I would like to know to which recipient(s) the message has been sent. I explicitly do *not* want to rewrite `offer1@...` or `offer2@...` to `offers`; I just would like to find out the message's recipient(s) if they are not in the `To:` header field.

Comment: That part was just to rule out that if you have such rewriting somewhere, you should remove it first. For rare use cases like this I personally find Postfix more flexible. My expertise is mail systems in general, and as an implementation I mostly use Postfix and Exchange. Hopefully someone else can answer the question *how* using *Sendmail*.

Comment: I could live with violating SMTP in this case. First, I can't imagine that anything bad would happen if such a header would be added (if choosing a GUID as header name so that it is unique .-)); second, in my case, after Sendmail has received that messages, *no further SMTP transactions will happen* (the messages will be delivered to `offers`'s inbox by using mechanisms other than SMTP instead of being relayed further).

Comment: Thanks for your additional comment. Could you please give me a hint where I should place that `NoRecipientAction=...` line? Placing it into `sendmail.mc` won't work ...

Comment: The `sendmail.mc` is a m4 macro file that is recommended for building the `sendmail.cf` master configuration file. There, the options are specified with `define('option','value')` that creates the `0 option=value` entry to the `sendmail.cf`.

Comment: OK, thanks, The macro to use in `sendmail.mc` would be `confNO_RCPT_ACTION`. However, I think this won't help either because this macro strikes only if "if there are no legal recipient fields (To:, Cc: or Bcc:) in the message" (from the docs); in my case, there are such headers, but they obviously contain "fake" contents.

Comment: Yes. Well, Postfix adds that as an `X-Original-To:` header by default. So, if you keep having problems implementing this with Sendmail, that's one solution. Added that to my answer.